# open addressing vs chained hashing

Tags: c++, hash

Open addressing is usually faster than chained hashing. I am testing my code with successful researches with a low load factor (0.1) but I keep getting best time results for the chained hashing instead of the open addressing. The difference is very very little and sometimes open address is even faster but on an average of 100 inserts the time is better with chained hasing.

I used a `vector<string>` as hash table for open addressing and a `vector<list<string> >` for chained hasing and universal hasing for both.

This is the part of the code about successful researches that I am timing:

#### Chained hashing research:

```
for (auto it_ric = this->hash[key].begin(); it_ric != this->hash[key].end(); it_ric++)
{
    if ((*it_ric) == string)
    {
        found = true;
    }
}
```

#### Open addressing:

```
while (found == false && key != hash.size())
{
    if (hash[key] == string)
    {
        key = hash.size();
        found = true;
    }
    else if (hash[key] == "")
    {
        key = hash.size();
        found = true;
    }
    else
    {
        key++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use quadratic probing (instead of linear) in open addressing.

Comment: Also, I don't know how compiler optimizes `hash[key] == ""`, but naively that's comparison of `string` to `char*`, which warrants creation of a useless temporary object.

Comment: I am confused, am I using linear probing? I am just incrementing key of 1 which I thought resembled linear probing but it's not really it. I calculate the keys with universal hasing.

About the string, how can I prevent the creation of that object?